# connecting to access database using MFC CDatabase in VS2012 and windows 8 x64

Tags: database, visual-c++, mfc

To connect a access database by Programming with MFC, using visual studio 2012 update 1 installed on windows 8 x64, the following code throws exception, which did not happened before in vs2010 and windows 7 x64. Is there any thing changed about the ODBC manager and how should I change the connection string.

```
CDatabase db;
db.OpenEx(TEXT("ODBC;Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dsn='';Dbq='d:\\databases\\a.mdb'");
```

and the exception message:

```
'Data source name not found and no default driver specified'
```

It does not work for accdb file too.

Comment: Unless it's a typo, you missed the "M" on the front of "Microsoft".

Comment: are you sure that the ODBC drivers in x64 is called the same as in x86. Also, get rid of Dsn=''. You are supposed to use either Driver or Dsn, but not both

Comment: Actually I made  the typo (missing M) here. not the original code.

Comment: almost all the connection string templates does have the Dsn='' and removing that do not help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cha in the comments was correct since by default only x64 ODBC driver is present in windows 8 for MFC applications compiling in win32 platform It is necessary to install ODBC driver in x86. It could be downloaded from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255